# Can't send date and time data using put http method in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

i'm trying to send Date and time through an api that I have developed in my backend. The api works perfectly with postman but once I try it in flutter it doesn't read the date and the time inputs (sets an empty value in the db table).

here is my code for the api service:

```
Future<AnalysisModel?> postAnalysis(
      String param, String deadline, String timing) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('${baseUrl}/api/v1/analysis'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "input_wanted_param": param,
        "input_deadline": deadline,
        "input_time": timing,
      }),
    );
  }
```

my model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<AnalysisModel> analysisModelFromJson(String str) =>
    List<AnalysisModel>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((x) => AnalysisModel.fromJson(x)));

String analysisModelToJson(List<AnalysisModel> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class AnalysisModel {
  AnalysisModel({
    required this.wanted_param,
    required this.deadline,
    required this.timing,
    required this.status,
  });

  String wanted_param;
  String deadline;
  String timing;
  String status;

  factory AnalysisModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AnalysisModel(
        wanted_param: json["wanted_param"],
        deadline: json["deadline"],
        timing: json["timing"],
        status: json["status"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "wanted_param": wanted_param,
        "deadline": deadline,
        "timing": timing,
        "status": status,
      };
}
```

and my ui page in which i'm sending 3 values (from a textfield and 2 inputfields):

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Remplir la demande d'analyse",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                      controller: TypeController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.usb_outlined),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
                        hintText: "Type",
                        labelText: "Type de l'analyse",
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kTextColor),
                        ),
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: kTextColor),
                          gapPadding: 2,
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                InputField(
                  controller: _dateController,
                  isEnabled: false,
                  hint: '${_selectedDate.toString()}',
                  label: 'Date limite',
                  iconOrdrop: 'button',
                  widget: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.date_range,
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _selectDate(context);
                      print(_dateController);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                InputField(
                  isEnabled: false,
                  controller: _startTimeController,
                  label: 'Heure limite',
                  iconOrdrop: 'button',
                  hint: _startDate.toString(),
                  widget: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.access_time,
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _selectStartTime(context);
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80, vertical: 30),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 5,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: MaterialButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
                  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await postAnalysis(TypeController.text,
                        _dateController.text, _startTimeController.text);
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Demande déposée');
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Déposer demande",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

As I explained above, only the textfield's data is saved into the database table, but not the other inputs which are date and time. Can anyone help me out with it? I'm struggling to solve this issue, thanks in advance!

Comment: what kind of datetime are you sending through postman..

Comment: I'm just sending them as Strings like "input_time":"07:48"